# There are (at least) two questions which have ghost notice on meta

Tags: bug, bounties, revisions-list, post-notices

[First](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/60505/revisions) and [second](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/100121/revisions). You can click "Return to Question" and see no actual notice.

There was a bounty added by a user in both questions, and then manually removed by moderator. In most cases, the notice is usually removed with the bounty, but in these two cases the notices weren't removed. Although they can't be seen without going to revisions. I've found those two questions by searching for [`hasnotice:yes locked:no`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=hasnotice%3Ayes+locked%3Ano).

This probably could affect other sites as well.